# cookie created by JavaScript not picked up by php page loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I'm writing a blog program ... as a little programming exercise for myself. The blog has a front-page (index.php), which contains a div showing all the posts. The div also contains links allowing users to filter what they see on the page with an AJAX function, which calls updatePage.php to request the filtered results from the server and update the div with the result.

Every time users click on the links, the page does two things - 1) set a cookie (with javascript) containing the user's filter request; 2) call updatePage.php, which uses PHP to read the request info from the cookie, then request data and update the div according to the request.

However, updatePage.php doesn't seem to be reading the cookie set in the AJAX function (returning an empty result). I pause the AJAX function in the debugger, and see that the cookie is set before updatePage.php.

Any idea what may have gone wrong here? Thanks!

Jeff

Comment: Why aren't you using url parameters? eg.: `updatePage.php?filter=` ?

Comment: Check if cookie has the same domain (www.domain.com != .domain.com != domain.com). Fastest way to achieve it is to generate a cookie from a backend and check if its domain is 1:1 copy of your, generated via js.

Comment: Hi Gabe, I want users to be able to add/remove different filters multiple times (such as looking for an article with tag A and B, by author C and D, etc). I figured cookie could be an easier way to do it in terms of coding ... or is there a better way to do it?

Hi eeree I've tried creating a cookie from PHP in sandbox page ... domains are the exactly same. What else could be the problem?

Thanks so much again!